# Why Does Output of This Command to a File Work Differently Inside a .BAT Script?

Tags: batch-file

```
wmic process get name,Processid,commandline >> test2.txt
```

Works just dandy from the CMD.EXE. However, it does not work from a .BAT script (no output file is changed or generated). The echo output reads as follows:

```
wmic process get name,Processid,commandline  1>>test2.txt
```

What is that "1" doing there? Is it a reflection of the handle? Why does this work differently and how can I address it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `1` is the number of the file descriptor you're redirecting. If you leave out a file descriptor in a redirection, `1` (STDOUT) is implicitly assumed. For more information see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

As for your command, it's working just fine for me both in a batch file and directly in `CMD`.

Comment: I found why it wasn't working: I had forgotten the executing user had a different "home" or start directory location, and the output path is relative. Thanks for your explanation on the "1".